# Searching for meta_key returns 0 posts

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, views

I am currently on a client project and I am stuck with the `meta_key` search in `WP_Query`. I am querying some other parts of the homepage successfully with the `WP_Query` class, but when I am passing `array( 'meta_key' => 'views' )` into the `WP_Query` initializer it's not working and no posts are returned (I am using the WP-PostViews plugin for the views counter, if this is the problem.

Would be nice to have someone with a fix. **Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To narrow down the possible causes I'd strongly recommend using a debugging plugin on your development server, like [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), so you can see the SQL being generated by your query. Alternatively check the `request` property of your `$wp_query` object.

It's always possible, if you only recently installed the plugin, that there aren't any posts with that post meta. Looking at WP-PostViews' source code and testing it myself I've found it only adds or updates the `view` post meta when a post/page is published or when it's visited. As such, any posts/pages created before the plugin was installed that haven't been viewed since will have no post meta. If you've been on the admin end of your dev server this entire time then it's possible there legitimately are no posts with any `views` post meta. If you check the `wp_postmeta` column of your WP install you can check this for yourself.